# How to get redirect url in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my project I send simple request for authorization :

```
http.Response response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
```

In response I has cookieID and other information, but I doesnt receive redirect url.

How I can take him?

Answer (score 17):

As jamesdlin has mentioned above and this [github issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/142) mentions, http has redirects set to true by default. To avoid redirect followRedirects needs to be set to false. The redirectUri can be fetched as follows:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

http.Request req = http.Request("Get", Uri.parse(YOUR_URL_HERE))..followRedirects = false;
http.Client baseClient = http.Client();
http.StreamedResponse response = await baseClient.send(req);
Uri redirectUri = Uri.parse(response.headers['location'])
```

Comment: Damn. Dart adds nothing meaningful to the programming landscape and will be forever the shoved-trough-your-throat flutter-language. Literally had to copy all those lines as it could not be as simple and self explanatory like in Python: `r = requests.get('http://github.com', allow_redirects=False)`

Answer (score 3):

By default, `package:http` and the underlying `HttpClient` will follow HTTP redirects automatically.

If you don't want this, then you can disable it by setting [`HttpClientRequest.followRedirects`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/HttpClientRequest/followRedirects.html) to `false`.

`package:http` exposes this through [`BaseRequest.followRedirects`](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/BaseRequest/followRedirects.html).